# What is the opposite of procrastination in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I thought of **precrastination** at first but that appears to be the act of planning to procrastinate.

Comment: concrastination?

Comment: I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: @Robusto: +1 But you see, I waited longer than you to say that much. Make haste slowly, maan. Lol.

Comment: so from the answers and comments, Proactive, Punctual and Procrastinate are the words to describe doing something before time, on time and late.. good question!

Comment: Precrastination seems to be a neologism. From a quick search it appears that it's sometimes used to mean the act of anticipating something.

Comment: procrastinate -> anticrastinate! obviously.

Comment: The opposite of procrastinate is technically "PhD". But that's an abbreviation for multiple words.

Comment: What about zeal or diligence?

Comment: @detly: I would have thought "PhD" is an example of procrastination...

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: I agree, but perhaps also apocrastinate?

Comment: @detly "Piled Higher and Deeper", right?

Comment: *eagerness*....

Comment: SE would not let me add an answer. I have to write rubbish answers to random questions so that I can gain enough "reputation" to be able to answer here. Instead of procrastinating, I chose to answer this question right now - even if it means that I have to offer an answer in a comment - it is all the fault of Stackexchange forcing me to do this. Anyway, I suggest "to implement" (something) as being the antonym of "to procrastinate (something).

Answer (score 45):

If to *[procrastinate](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=procrastinate)* is "to put off doing something," then its antonym is *[anticipate](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=anticipate)* — "to deal with beforehand."

So you can say the opposite of *procrastination* is *anticipation*.

If you can live with more than one word, a clearer antonym of *procrastination* is *being [proactive](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=proactive)*. Being *proactive* doesn't carry the extraneous associations that *anticipation* might for some people.

Comment: Proactive is a much better word than anticipate, in my opinion. When I hear "John anticipates doing his homework," I get the mental image of John being excited, even happy, to do his homework each night. If I hear "John is proactive about doing his homework," then I get a much more realistic picture.

Comment: To procrastinate is "to delay something needlessly", I don't think that 'anticipate' captures the antonym.

Answer (score 34):

I suggest **alacrity**.

> [alacrity](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alacrity)
> noun
> \ə-ˈla-krə-tē\
>
> promptness in response : cheerful readiness [accepted the invitation with alacrity]

Also **precipitation** means acting suddenly and rashly, bearing a negative meaning and covering the other end of the spectrum.

Comment: I like this very much. Alacrity is a good answer here.

Comment: Alacrity is nice, but does it have a verb form?

Answer (score 21):

You could go with "timeliness." Notionally, "proactive" gets at the sense of the word you want, but it's the wrong part of speech.

Other candidates: advance, accelerate, complete, etc.

Comment: +1 The relevance here is that the spirit of procrastination is in putting off something till later, timeliness is not putting off something till later, but rather doing it on time.  @gnawme referenced anticipation and proactive, which are close, but the spirit with them is doing or thinking about something before it is due, rather than on-time.  A little bit different.

Comment: I think this is clearly the best answer. It's the only one that really stands in polarity on the the correct axis.

Answer (score 12):

**Prioritization**

In Covey's "The 7 Habits of Highly Effective People" the author refers to the opposite of *procrastination* as *prioritization* in his chapter on "First Things First".

This is honestly the only word that makes sense in every day speech. No one would say to *anticipate* one's tasks, but it makes a lot of sense to *prioritize* one's tasks.

Comment: There is indeed an understanding that procrastination is to replace high-priority tasks with lower ones. In that point of view prioritize is the perfect antonym.

Comment: You can prioritize -- come up with a detailed list of what must be done -- yet still procrastinate.

Comment: It does make sense, because procrastination infers putting off an important task. If you put off something trivial so that you can have more time for something important and life threatening, then nobody would call this procrastinating. However the opposite would be procrastination. 
However as someone else noticed, "prioritizing" is an the answer only if it means setting priorities and also implementing them.

Answer (score 9):

I like the word *[expedite](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expedite)*, "to accelerate the progress of".  It has a minor drawback that the form parallel to *procrastination*, that is, *[expedition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expedition)*, ordinarily has the sense of an excursion or voyage, and its sense "the quality of being expedite" is obsolete.  However, some [synonyms](http://www.onelook.com/?w=%2a&loc=revfp2&clue=expedite) of expedite, such as  *hasten, speed, hurry, accelerate* have suitable forms including *hastening, speedup, speeding-up, hurry-up, acceleration* that may serve.

Answer (score 9):

Do.  Hmm, well it won't let me answer that succinctly so I'll repeat myself: the opposite of procrastinate is *do*.

Comment: I love this answer.  Although i would add to it slightly by making it a command. Do it (or decide you won't do it and move on)!

Answer (score 6):

I believe the word you are looking for is **action**.

> [action](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/action)
> noun
>
> 1. the process or state of acting or of being active: The machine is not in action now.

Comment: I sense we are lone voices in the wilderness here, but I agree. To *procrastinate* is to delay instead of acting, so the opposite is to act instead of delaying. When urgent problems need to be addressed, you don't need *procrastination*, you need *action*.

Comment: Seems *somebody* disagrees...

Comment: -1 To procrastinate means, yes, to delay but it does not mean "non-action". The act or deed is performed, *eventually*. And who said one has to procrastinate urgent problems? For example I always procrastinate doing the ironing. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I absolutely agree that it's good to justify (vocally, in a comment) downvotes. (For reasons just demonstrated.) // Not sure I follow about preference - do you mean pref in deciding 'whether this is useful' or 'what a downvote signifies'?  If the former, I agree - if the latter .. meh, maybe a Meta discussion if you want to bother.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe *industry* or *industriousness*. Although as opposites, they imply an element of laziness exists with procrastination, and I'm not sure that's always the case.

Answer (score 4):

Dialogue in comments has revealed that the correct Latin inverse would be **antecrastination**, which would mean roughly "doing something before tomorrow".

Answer (score 3):

I propose **[dispatch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispatch)**:

> : to dispose of (as a task) rapidly or efficiently

Comment: That isn't quite an antonym. Procrastinate has an implicit referral to another time period in it. So, the opposite should carry with it the meaning that something is done in advance of when it needs to be done. Good effort though.

Answer (score 2):

The opposite Greek prefix to *pro-* is *epi-*, as seen in Prometheus (forethought) and his brother Epimetheus (afterthought).  So it stands to reason that the antonym of procrastination is **epicrastination**.

Comment: But this is the Latin prefix, not the Greek prefix. And I'm afraid it would be odd to use "cras" ("tomorrow") to move something to an earlier time...

Comment: @Cerberus: Oops, that's unfortunate.  Hoist by my own octopus.

Comment: Sticking to Latin, and taking the opposite of tomorrow, now, it should be innunctiation then (into now). I have a feeling this one is not gonna make it...

Comment: maybe antecrastinate before tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about simply **"zeal"** or **"diligence"**?

While these aren't really antonyms to **"procrastination"** (which is putting off doing something), they capture the opposite meaning of the ideas of *"laziness"* and *"delayed action"* that are associated with it.

### **zeal**

From the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zeal):

> - a strong feeling of interest and enthusiasm that makes someone very eager or determined to do something
> - eagerness and ardent interest in pursuit of something

From the [Oxford British-English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/zeal):

> Great energy or enthusiasm in pursuit of a cause or an objective

### Diligence

From the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diligence):

> - persevering application, assiduity
>
>   - *Obsolete:* speed, haste
> - the attention and care legally expected or required of a person (as a party to a contract)

From the [Oxford British-English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diligence):

> Careful and persistent work or effort.

Comment: +1 for zeal, it was the word that jumped to my mind on seeing the question

Answer (score 1):

**Anticrastination** appears to have [gained some traction](https://www.google.com/search?q=anticrastination).

Comment: When the first result is from Urban Dictionary, I wouldn't say that this traction is anything reliable.

Comment: @Mahnax: I would be at pains to avoid that implication, yes.

Comment: "Anti" is a Greek preposition, not a Latin one. It is true that it is sometimes mistakenly used instead of Latin "ante" (probably owing to French), but better not. And cras "tomorrow" doesn't really work anyway...

Comment: Actually, I like antecrastination.  It seems to imply that I'll do the job BEFORE tomorrow.  Which might be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Two neologisms present themselves, one I like and one I don't.

One is *sticktoitive*. A tenacity or tendency to see things through to completion.

The other is *git-r-done*.

Answer (score 1):

(I much preferred @Lotus Notes suggestion: Prioritization.)

My proposal is:

### Promptness

If we consider that procrastination is the unwillingness to perform an action which leads to its continual postponement but not necessarily to its inactivity then we can see how [**promptness**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/promptness) is its exact antonym.

Answer (score 0):

The emotional emphasis in  "to procrastinate" is the needlessness of the delay. The way I would think of antonyms would be to see what words I would use to emphasize the negation:

For example,

```
"Billy is diligent about finishing homework, he does not procrastinate". (Sense of duty)
```

OR

```
"Sarah procrastinates under stress, I wish she were more volitional" (Sense of giving up)
```

My suggestion is that you try and use it following similar idea of trying to emphasize a particular idea or thought, and see how many ways you can use procrastinate in a sentence... You'll have your antonyms.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "**determination**", which stems from *determinare*, to bring to an end, have a fixed direction and goal.

Other terms may be decisiveness, resoluteness, conclusiveness.

I might tell my minions that I want to see "action", not procrastination.

Answer (score 0):

Tersely: *proactiveness* or *proaction*, depending on the contrast and degree of anticipatory behavior you're trying to convey.

([Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=proaction).)

Answer (score 0):

**Productivity**

In the sense that it commonly means getting things done, as opposed to putting them off for later, which is the general meaning of procrastinate.